# How to turn off SMTP port in Solaris

Tags: solaris, sendmail, smtp

I  want to turn off SMTP port in Solaris server.

I am getting follwing Message.

```
/var/adm/messages:Mar 10 06:18:08 sendmail[20024]: [ID 702911 mail.alert]
/var/adm/messages:Mar 11 06:18:08 sendmail[25277]: [ID 702911 mail.alert]
```

So i have tried for Disabling sendmail by using below commands.

```
# svcadm disable svc:/network/smtp:sendmail
# svcadm disable svc:/network/sendmail-client
```

But nothing happens. I need to turn off SMTP port.

Comment: does `svcadm disable sendmail` not work?

Comment: have you checked if the port is really open with netstat? what is the output of svcs |grep sendmail?

Comment: 'Output: svcs |grep sendmail    
    disabled       Mar_23   svc:/network/smtp:sendmail'     
But still i  am having this error

Comment: You've achieved one goal of "turning off the port"; the syslog message seems to be cut short.  It's possible that the local sendmail is still trying to deliver something.

Comment: Mar 24 06:18:08 btcsp01 sendmail[10256]: [ID 702911 mail.alert] unable to qualify my own domain name (btcsp01) -- using short name

Comment: this is the actual error message. but now we cant change the domain name now. thats why i want to turnoff SMTP port

Answer (score 1):

you problem has nothing to do with the sendmail and if the port is open. It is a well know message that can be safely ignored. 
If you want to get rid of that message, you can add in your /etc/hosts the FQDN of your server.
example of current entry

```
192.166.0.123    btcsp01
```

What will remove the messages

```
192.168.0.123    btcsp01 btcsp01.mydomain.com
```

Comment: I also know i can be ignored. But i am searching for an option to avoid this message

Comment: I just provided you with the solution on my answer. in fact you can also just the hostname with a  . in the end. btcsp01 btcsp01. and the messages will go away after reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your issue, or why you think sendmail or something else is running on the SMTP port.  Also no mention on if you're using Solaris 10, or 11.

Ideally you'll want at least the nullclient configured so that any possible system or product events/alerts can be sent to alert admins and users of issues.

And if you don't want sendmail, just uninstall the package if you're not going to use it.